# Is it 100% guaranteed that a process that listens to blockchain events will receive them if they get emitted?

Tags: solidity, events, security, nodes

When a smart contract emits an `event`, if I am listening to them for example with an application that stores all events from that smart contract into a database, do I have the certainty that I won't miss any? How can I be sure about that?

Comment: Yes, you will not miss any emitted event. I had run such node script before and it did well for listening to the events. In that case your server should be always connected to the internet and no restart or anything, otherwise you can listen and put in database all event records.

Comment: What happens if I disconnect or restart? Can't I get the latest events when the node is synchronising again with the network?

Comment: Yes you keep geting latest events but old events are lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out Moralis streams API
https://docs.moralis.io/streams-api

Where you get 100% guaranteed delivery for streaming blockchain events

You can check more here https://docs.moralis.io/streams-api/tutorials

Disclosure: I work at Moralis